# Select rows which have a numeric value in the first cell (Column A)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to try and select a range of rows on my spread sheet which are located below the last row with a numeric value in column A. Row 40 is where I need to select from, but this location will change. How do I perform a selection based on a non numeric value. Currently I am selecting the range of rows and deleting them using the following

```
Rows("40:40").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim LastRow as Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count    

For row = 2 To LastRow
    If Not IsNumeric(Cells(row, 1)) Then
        row = row+1
        Rows(row).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next row
```

Comment: I was bending my mind a bit, therefore a lot of edits, but this version should work. Although I haven't tried it out, so no guarantees there ;)

Comment: I made small modification to your answer for more useful.

Comment: Thanks all. Currently having issues with the following line -->                      Rows(row:row).Select

Comment: I assume this is because row here --> For row = 2 To LastRow   --- will become capitalized.

Comment: @AMorton1989 row will not become capitalised. I copied this from the code you had and replaced 40 with row. Try Rows(row).Select, perhaps that works better.

Comment: Ah I have just realised what the issue is. When you put a variable within Rows.Select, it needs to be in the following format. --> Rows(Row & ":" & Row).Select

Comment: @AMorton1989 yes that is also true if you want to retain that layout. Now as I come to think of it your row will probably capitalize as you have declared it in that way, and I declared it without a capital R, hence the difference. The makeup you now use for Rows().Select is more used when you want to select multiple rows, if you only select one row you can do with Rows(Row).Select. Also see: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/entire-rows-columns.html

Comment: I also fixed the problem with the Rows().Select in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Final result.

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'In this instance I am starting from row 6.
For Row = 6 To LastRow
    If Not IsNumeric(Cells(row, 1)) Then

        Rows(Row & ":" & Row).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next Row
```